# How to parse JET/ACE SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, parsing, ms-access, jet

I want to emphasize that I am looking for the "right" way to do something like this in general and for Access in particular.  What I have below is the solution I came up with for use on a SQL Server, but if it's not right, or if it won't work on Access, I'd like to know that too.

For the purposes of providing a ProgressBar I have the following function that I use to generate a (possibly more efficient) SQL statement to return the number of records that will be returned by the SQL Statement *sql*.  It works against a SQL Server 2008 database.  I would like to use a similar treatment for Access databases, but I have found nothing analogous to TSql100Parser and Sql100ScriptGenerator for JET/ACE.  Does such a thing exist?  Is there a better general solution?

```
Imports Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom
Imports Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql

Private Function GetCountSQL(ByVal sql As String) As String
    Dim _tsBatch As TSqlBatch
    Dim _peErrors As IList(Of ParseError) = Nothing
    Dim _tssFragment As TSqlScript
    Dim _tspParser As New TSql100Parser(False)
    Dim _retval As String = vbNullString
    Dim _sgScriptGenerator As New Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql.Sql100ScriptGenerator
    Dim _tsStatement As TSqlStatement

    _tssFragment = _tspParser.Parse(New StringReader(sql), _peErrors)
    If _peErrors Is Nothing OrElse _peErrors.Count = 0 Then
        For Each _tsBatch In _tssFragment.Batches
            For Each _tsStatement In _tsBatch.Statements
                If TypeOf _tsStatement Is Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql.SelectStatement AndAlso CType(_tsStatement, Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql.SelectStatement).OrderByClause IsNot Nothing Then
                    CType(_tsStatement, Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql.SelectStatement).OrderByClause = Nothing
                End If
            Next
        Next
        _sgScriptGenerator.GenerateScript(_tssFragment, _retval)
        _retval = String.Format("Select Count(*) FROM ({0}) SQ", _retval)
    End If
    Return _retval
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find something like this for Access. This parser itself is fairly new. I would suggest that just about the only thing to do would be to use regex based parsing. if all you want is a column count you could use regex to locate the list and a split function to count the columns.